# How to disable the screen name when loading twitter follow button asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
    var twitterWidgets = document.createElement('script');
    twitterWidgets.type = 'text/javascript';
    twitterWidgets.async = true;
    twitterWidgets.src = 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(twitterWidgets);
  })();
</script>
```

When this loads, i need it to just show just the follow button, not the name of who you're following. When using the iframe you can add a query argument for show_screen_name.

I tried doing this:

```
twitterWidgets.show_screen_name = false;
```

but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with `data-show-screen-name="false"` like this:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/twitterapi" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow @twitterapi</a>
```

Twitter has a special note with this option:

> Note that if you decide to set the
>   show_screen_name parameter to false,
>   you’ll still have to display
>   “manually” which @username the Follow
>   button is interacting with. In other
>   words, it has to be very clear who the
>   user is going to follow by clicking
>   your Follow Button.